# Trigger to substract from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have two tables

```
Table Number1              Table:  Number2 



Position1                    Position2
   2                           2
   3                           3
   4                           1
```

**Table Number3** will be the result of **Number1 - Number2** by row. 
How I could make trigger to do that?
 I've been searching but it just said i can't do something like that. Please give me some solution.

Comment: Why on earth are these differant tables?

Comment: Tables have **no** inherent order. For anything "by row" to make sense, we need a column by which to determine the order.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, because you cannot readily find the "last" row.  You need an id or creation date or version.

A SQL query that will come close to what you want is:

```
select n1.number - n2.number
from (select n1.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from number1 n1 
     ) n1 join
     (select n2.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from number2 n2
     ) n2
     on n1.number = n2.number
```

This attempts to assign a sequential number, in order, to the rows in each table.  However, this is not guarateed.  It might work for small tables.  And it might work when you have only one thread doing the processing.  But there are no guarantees.

Comment: how I can use it as trigger?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, unless you have a column that specifies ordering.

Comment: I just confused how I could use trigger to substract values from two different tables.

Comment: @user2063311 . . . You don't use a trigger to subtract values.  You use a trigger to populate a column in some table whose value is the difference between the two values.  So, you need to create triggers for whenever one of the values change -- an insert trigger, an update trigger, and a delete trigger.  However, if you have proper indexes on the tables, the query to do the difference should be so efficient that a trigger is unnecessary.